# Validating ReCaptcha in Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, recaptcha

I am using ReCaptcha's ASP.NET plugin from https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet I have implemented ReCaptcha on my ASP.NET form and it works. The problem is that the validation happens on the server side only, thus when a wrong captcha is entered, the FileUpload control on the page loses it's value, and the user has to again browse to the file and select it. This is because ViewState does not store the users' local path(would be a security violation if it could!).

To avoid this problem, I was thinking of adding an additional validation on the client with JS before the form is submitted. The Submit button would call a JS function that checks if ReCaptcha is valid and if not, show the user an error and reload a new Captcha(on the client) without losing the Upload control state instead of posting back to the server and losing the HTML upload state. I am not able to find documentation about how to validate and reload ReCaptcha in JS in this scenario.

Comment: wouldn't that defeat the entire purpose of ReCaptcha

Comment: The reason you don't validate captcha on the client is because, necessarily, you're sending the answer to the client. So now it's trivial to automate the cracking, because no cracking is required. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of ReCaptcha is server-side validation.  If you want to validate it client-side, you'll have to send the answer to the client.  And if you do that, you've defeated the whole purpose of using the Captcha - the client will have access to the correct answer.